# iptables REDIRECT in combination with matching on interface vs. IP address

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I've successfully set up Tor for [transparent proxying](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TransparentProxy) using iptables (ie, all outgoing traffic is sent through Tor without the application's knowledge). In doing so, I discovered both an odd problem and an equally odd fix (workaround?).

My rules are as follows. No user-defined chains or other rules present, all policies are ACCEPT.

```
-t nat -A OUTPUT -o lo -j RETURN
-t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner tor -j RETURN
-t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --syn -j REDIRECT --to-ports 54
-t nat -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 55

-A INPUT -j ACCEPT

-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT # Rule A
-A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT # Rule B
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner tor -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -j REJECT # Rule C
```

In other words:

- All traffic from/to localhost is untouched.
- All traffic generated by Tor is untouched.
- All outgoing TCP connections are sent through Tor (transparent proxying port is 54).
- All outgoing DNS queries are resolved by Tor (DNS on port 55).
- To prevent leakage, all other outgoing traffic is hit on the head with a brick and dropped in a ditch.

(While this setup has some problems, like failing to respond to connections from the LAN, those are irrelevant to the issue at hand.)

If Rule B is not present, all outgoing connections are immediately rejected by Rule C. I know they are rejected by Rule C because changing the rejection type (ex. `--reject-with icmp-proto-unreachable`) results in a different error. Example error messages without Rule B:

```
# With Rule C --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable, the default:
$ curl 213.155.151.153 # (google.com; DNS also doesn't work)
curl: (7) Failed connect to 213.155.151.153:80; Connection refused

# With Rule C --reject-with icmp-proto-unreachable:
$ curl 213.155.151.153
curl: (7) Failed connect to 213.155.151.153:80; Protocol not available
```

With Rule B, connections work fine.

Based on my understanding of iptables, when an outgoing TCP connection is made, the third rule in OUTPUT chain of `nat` will rewrite the packet's destination to 127.0.0.1:54. The packet will then enter OUTPUT chain of `filter`, and it *should* be matched by Rule A, since its outgoing interface is now the loopback interface. However, it is *not* matched by Rule A, and if Rule B (which does match it) is not present, the packet gets dragged into an alley and mugged by Rule C.

Why aren't Rule A and Rule B equivalent? How is matching the loopback interface different from matching the loopback address, in this situation?

Comment: Further research indicates that this may be because there is no routing decision between `nat` OUTPUT and `filter` OUTPUT. So even if the packet's destination address is altered, its outgoing interface is not updated until after `filter` OUTPUT. I'm not sufficiently confident to make this an answer though.